# What is the difference between density and lowest energy states for Higgs field?

Tags: higgs

The density of the Higgs field is zero everywhere in the universe despite the fact that the expansion of space is accelerating, and then the lowest energy states on average for the higgs field is non-zero or 246GeV to be exact. What is the difference between this 2 concepts? Also the mass of Higgs boson is 125GeV, this number I can understand it is how strongly it is interacting with itself... Oh boy actually please explain all 3 concepts